# How does google "change background image" link work?

Tags: javascript

When I look the source of this link, there is just this function

```
javascript:void(0)
```

and there is nothing else, I looked for usage of javascript:void(0) but there is not much place where it is used alone. So what is the secret ?

Comment: Google is one of the best sites i have seen for not letting people know how they did stuff. they are very clever at this. B****rds

Comment: Which link? Do you mean the Google home page?

Comment: @Dolmen, Yes the link at the bottom left part of the google homepage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the source:

```
<div id=cpf style="display: none; margin: 0 8px; position: relative;"class=fade><a href="javascript:void(0)" style="bottom: 0;display:inline;font-family:arial, san-serif;font-size:small;left:0;position:absolute;">Change background image</a></div>
.....
var a=document.getElementById("cpf");
.....
var c=a.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
if(!c.onclick)c.onclick=function(){
var d="https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?continue\x3dhttp://www.google.com/webhp%3Fhl%3Den%26cplp%3D\x26hl\x3den\x26service\x3dig\x26ltmpl\x3daddphoto";
.....
```

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere else there's a javascript function which attaches to the `onclick` event. Here's an example with [jquery](http://jquery.com/):

```
$('#linkid').click(function() {
    window.location.href = 'http://yahoo.com';
    return false;
});
```

So it is possible to attach javascript actions to DOM elements. Those javascript functions can be located in some other files that are included which are obfuscated, so don't be surprised that you don't find it. A good tool such as [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) could help you debug through JS code.

Comment: and the link doesn't seem to be having an Id ? I am looking at it using firebug. What is the #linkid here ?

Comment: Using the `id` is not the only way to find a DOM element. Take a look at the selectors (http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: @stckvrflw: the id of the enclosing div is used, see my post.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, jQuery adds a `onclick` event somewhere. In Chrome, right click the link and choose Inspect element. In the bottom right, there should be a section at the bottom called Event Listeners. That will show you what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

```
var a=document.getElementById("cpf")
```

The div surrounding the link has an id of 'cpf'.  The bit above references that.  Search for 'cpf' and you'll see one other reference.  I haven't analyzed how the JS works, but this is likely how the anchor tag is referenced.

Edit:

I use the [Web Developer toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60/) for Firefox to look at the JavaScript on a page, with a little less hassle.